# Management of internet connections?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10-desktop

The status says - connected.

[image]

In windows 10 I have list of configured internet connections, how I can get that list and connect to or disconnect from one of them programmatically with C++?

Comment: [About the Network List Manager API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965303(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to  take a look at https://www.codeproject.com/articles/574446/using-network-list-manager-cplusplus

I hope this will help you also I provide you full project source I learned from it.